# What does an officer mean by custodial statement?

Tags: criminal-law, canada, arrest

If (in Canada) a police officer asks you to come in to make a *custodial statement* does this mean you will be placed under arrest?

Comment: What's a custodial statement? I've never heard of it before (and google searches yield me nothing)

Comment: I assume it is a statement during a custodial interrogation. A custodial interrogation is where you are not free to go, though it is not clear whether that means you are *ipso facto* under arrest.